# When does $BG \to BA$ loop to a homomorphism?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, classifying-spaces, loop-spaces

If I have a compact connected Lie group $G$ and a (relatively nice) simply-connected topological abelian group $A$, when is it the case that a given $f\colon BG \to BA$ loops to a (continuous) *homomorphism* $G\to A$? This seems like it can't always be true, and also should be some kind of classical result, but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: Should that be "when is $BG\to BA$ the delooping of a homomorphism"?

Comment: A more usual way of posing the question is: when does an $E_1$-homomorphism come from a map of topological groups? I don't know the answer though, but it is not always

Comment: @DenisNardin yes, that's another way I was thinking of it.

Comment: @MarkGrant yes, sorry, my mistake. Edited the title, too.

Comment: $E_1$ or $A_∞$ (they are the same thing) control associativity. $E_∞$ is the commutative one. The other $E_n$ interpolate between the two (e.g. $E_2$ gives braided multiplication). $H_∞$ is the "shadow" of $E_∞$ in the homotopy category

Comment: Does this have anything to do with similar question "when does a morphism of stacks $BG\rightarrow BH$ is coming from a morphism of Lie groups $G\rightarrow H$"???

Comment: @Denis ok. And no, $G$ is not abelian.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik no, nothing at all. That answer is easy in comparison: they all do.

Comment: Oh. Ok ok :) @DavidRoberts

Comment: Unfortunately I think that this question is quite sensitive to $A$ and not just to $BA$. For example, $A$ does not have any homomorphisms from $G$ if it does not have any homomorphisms from $S^1$, which requires that it have elements of finite order $(g^n = 1)$; however, any classifying space $BA$ is equivalent to a classifying space $BA'$ where $A'$ has no finite-order elements.

Comment: @Tyler hmm, interesting. It may be my hopes are misplaced, then.

Comment: I'll point to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156408/equivariant-classifying-spaces-from-classifying-spaces?rq=1, which addresses a related question: what criteria imply that $\mathrm{Hom}(G,H)\to \mathrm{Map}_*(BG,BH)$ is a weak homotpy equivalence?  The answer there says nothing about your case I think, but perhaps the methods used could be helpful. I don't know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If $G$ is a compact connected topological group and $A$ is a locally compact abelian topological group, then for any map $f:BG\to BA$ the looped map $\Omega f:\Omega BG\to \Omega BA$ is homotopically equivalent to a homomorphism $\phi:G\to A$. This follows from the main result of

*Scheffer, Wladimiro*, [**Maps between topological groups that are homotopic to homomorphisms**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2038100), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 33, 562-567 (1972). [ZBL0236.22008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0236.22008).

I'm not sure if this answers your question, however, which seems to be about when $f$ is in the image of the classifying space functor $B:\mathsf{TopGrp}\to\mathsf{Top}$.

Comment: Thanks, you are indeed answering the intended question, but unfortunately I can't assume $A$ is locally compact! It is in my example the geometric realisation of a simplicial abelian Lie group.... But this is a good answer in any case.

Comment: Reformulation of the question: is $\hom(G,A) \to \hom_{A_\infty}(G,A)$ surjective on $\pi_0$?  (The target is $A_\infty$-homomorphisms $G \to A$).  One might be able to use Boardman-Vogt obstruction theory to study this, by replacing $G$ with a cofibrant $A_\infty$-space.

Comment: I will accept this in the absence of any other suggestions, because it shows how subtle the question is, and how much it will depend on the topology of $A$.